# How to remove white space at the top of my form?

Tags: html, css

I'm getting white spaces at the top of my form and I believe I have tried everything but, it's still there.  Can someone give some sugesstions at to how to get rid of the white space at the top? When I open the form in firefox it seems to be okay but, when I use IE I get white space.  Also, it is a .cfm form.  Thanks.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.body
{
margin-top:0px;
padding-top:0px;
}
.mytable1
{
border-collapse:collapse;
border-color:#000000; 
border-style:solid; 
border-width:2px;
}
.mytable1 th
{
border-color:#333333;
border-style:solid; 
border-width:1px;
}
.mytable1 td
{
border-color:#333333;
border-style:solid; 
border-width:1px;
}
.mytable1
{
border-collapse:collapse;
border-color:#000000; 
border-style:solid; 
border-width:2px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body lang=EN-US style='tab-interval:.5in'>
<div id=Section1>
<cfoutput>

<form name="reportform" action="UpdateFormStatus.cfm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="UserEmail" value="#search_review.UserEmail#">
  <table class="mytable1">
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="blacktext" align="center" colspan="14"><strong>Review Form</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top" class="blacktext" colspan="4"><strong>Type:</strong> #form.Type# </td>
      <td valign="top" class="blacktext" colspan="4"><strong>Number: </strong> #form.Number#   </td>         
    </tr>
    <cfif not search_results.RecordCount>
      <tr>
        <td class="blacktextbold" colspan="2"> No results match those criteria.</td>
         <td align="left" colspan="1"><a href="search_form.cfm">Search Again</a></td>
      </tr>
      <cfelse>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" colspan="3" class="blacktext"><strong>Name:</strong> #form.Name# </td>
        <td valign="top" colspan="3" class="blacktext"><strong>Project Code: </strong> #form.ProjectCode# </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</cfoutput>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have put `body` in as a class

is should be:

```
body{
margin-top:0px;
padding-top:0px;
}
```

For an ID you use `#` for a class you use `.` and if you are going to target an object like a div you just put `div`

Answer (score 0):

You should put the margin and padding from the html as well to 0 and remove the . from the body selector:

```
html, body
{
margin-top:0px;
padding-top:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the closing tag for `cfif`. The browser is trying to fix your html and is putting this tag above the table. You also don't have a closing tag for the div with `id="Section1"`. CFML is not the same as HTML btw. This will not render properly as HTML because of the Cold Fusion specific tags.

Comment: I have tried everything that was mentioned here but, nothing is working. If CFML is different then how should it be done?

Comment: Just to be sure, is the code you posted the source on the server side, or the page as it appears on the client side (view page source in the browser)? I'm assuming this is from the client side because of the `<!DOCTYPE HTML...` tag. If you see Cold Fusion markup on the client side, it means it wasn't rendered properly on the server side. If you've corrected the syntax errors in the source being hosted on the server and you're still having problems there may be something wrong with the way your CF server is set up. I suggest you add CF tags to your question.

Comment: First, try removing the blank line under `<cfoutput>`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the parent div.  `<div id="Section1">`  Also, as @Andrew mentioned, you had `body` set as a class. (`body {}` instead of `.body{}`).

http://jsfiddle.net/fKMHe/

Answer (score 0):

To remove the margin and padding from the `form` element just add this:

```
form
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
```